# Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [csv/users.csv] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using **Spring Boot Batch** example. In this example, I am looking to create CSV file using `FlatFileItemWriter`. The `writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("csv/users.csv"));` does not allow me to create the CSV file. I suspect what extra parameter do we need to give here ?

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Could not convert resource to file: [class path resource [csv/users.csv]]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.getOutputState(FlatFileItemWriter.java:399) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.open(FlatFileItemWriter.java:337) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:163) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:179) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:134) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:128) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:781) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.jackrutorial.SpringBatchDatabaseToCsvApplication.main(SpringBatchDatabaseToCsvApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [csv/users.csv] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:129) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.getOutputState(FlatFileItemWriter.java:396) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Here is the code snippet

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("csv/users.csv"));
        writer.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(false);
        writer.setShouldDeleteIfExists(false);

        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {
            {
                setDelimiter(",");
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "id", "name" });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return writer;
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `/` in front of `csv/users.csv`

Comment: @Luca - Sure. I will try your solution in some time. I had used something like below:
writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("output/users.csv"));

Comment: @Luca - With your suggestion, it gives error - Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [output/persons.csv] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist. Any other solution ?

Comment: Add code of your writer's config

Comment: Git hub link: https://github.com/JavaHelper/spring-boot-spring-batch/tree/master/SpringBootBatchDbToCsv

Comment: Classpath resource means you are trying to write to a file in your classpath (your jar) and this is not possible. Try use a filesystem resource with an absolute path as test

Comment: Right, but with the XML approaches its working. May be need to understand how it works refer 4.1 of the link : http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-mysql-database-to-xml/ The same I was looking to do

Comment: With high probabilities it is working during debug but not when code is executed from jar

Comment: Even without the debug mode its working very fine. Does that mean its a bug with the annotation based approached ?

Comment: IDK. You can debug the code and check because it doesnt work. Enjoy!

Comment: I'm getting the same error but `FatFileItemWrite` works fine with `ClassPathResource()`, its the `Partitioner` I'm getting the error with, especially when the filename is passed through stepExecutionContext, works fine if given directly. Any idea?